# What is uname-r | grep fc?

Tags: grep

I was reading a .sh file and find a line written as

```
if[ "`uname -r | grep fc`" == " " ]; then
```

But I don't find the meaning of `fc` and the whole expression.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are the typos in that line made by you or are they from the script?

Comment: The command in the question can never evaluate to `true`. Either `uname -r` contains the letters `fc`, in which case `grep` outputs that line. It is guaranteed to not equal a simple space character (as it has to contain at least the caracters "fc"). If, on the other hand, `uname -r` doesn't contain "fc", `grep` will output nothing which also is not equal to a single space. So both possible cases are `false`. That being said, can you please double check that you pasted the line exactly as written in the script, including all special characters and all spaces?

Comment: Example : `uname -r | grep fc` → 4.16.12-300. **fc28** .x86_64. ... I.e. checking if the kernel is Fedora. Seems to be from a driver install script  https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2282796.html : "Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installationscript", "November, 21 2011 v1.1.0"

Answer (score 1):

the special back tick char will return whatever is evaluated inside of the backticks. so `uname -r | grep fc`  will return something only if your kernel release contains the letters fc.  If no fc then it will just be the newline character. So the if statement will only evaluate to true when fc is not contained in your kernel string that is returned from uname. try doing

```
export a=`uname -r` 
echo $a
```

as a test